# Reference request - the topology generated by upward and downward closures of antichains.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, order-theory

By definition, the order topology on a totally ordered set $T$ is the coarsest topology such that every subset of $T$ that can be expressed as the upward or downward closure of a singleton is closed.

Now this definition still makes sense without the condition that $T$ is totally ordered. However, there doesn't seem to be a lot of interest in this generalization. Perhaps this is evidence that we're not generalizing correctly. One thing we might try is to replace "singleton" with "antichain." So the definition becomes:

> The order topology on a partially ordered set $P$ is the coarsest
>   topology such that every subset of $P$ that can be expressed as the
>   upward or downward closure of an antichain is closed.

This reduces to the usual definition under the assumption that $P$ is totally ordered.

What is currently known about this topology, and where can I learn more?

Comment: I presume you have tried googling for "order topology" and have found, for example, http://www.heldermann.de/R&E/RAE18/ctw05.pdf and didn't like it (?). You may find results of interest by searching for "alexandrov topology".

Comment: @RobArthan: It's not clear to me how the Alexandrov topology is relevant here.

Comment: I thought it was relevant because the topology the OP has in mind is an Alexandrov topology in many interesting cases, I  believe - see the book chapter that I gave a link to.

Comment: @RobArthan, thanks for the link. I think you have misread the definition given in the question. In particular, both upward *and* downward closures of antichains are defined to be topologically closed. Note, however, that this is a much weaker condition than simply stating that all upward closed and all downward closed sets are topologically closed.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen, thanks for the bounty man, I owe you one.

Comment: Don't mention it. Anyway, it seems to have done little good.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen, here's another idea. What if we define that the order topology on a quasi ordered set $Q$ is the coarsest topology such that: for all $A \subseteq Q$, the set of all upper bounds of $A$ is closed, and the set of all lower bounds of $A$ is closed. I'm not yet sure if this agrees on the totally ordered sets with the usual definition.

Comment: I think it does the right thing for total orders. On the other hand, in a complete lattice, the set of upper bounds of $A$ is simply the upward closure of $\{ \sup A \}$. That gets you almost back to where you started.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen, ah yes. Good point!